# accept() , close() methods On ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets

I create a chatting program. My server has a button , the button is for starting the server call accept() method on server socket , button for closing the server call close() on server socket.

When I re-press start button to re-accept connection on the same socket , accept method throws SocketException Socket is closed.

Comment: How can we help you ?  I have no idea. Please read FAQ. And please accepte answers on your others question too

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close(). You need to create new instance of ServerSocket and then call accept method on it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reopen a socket. If you want to use the variable again, you'll have to create and assign a new socket.

From the Java Documentation on [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()), see info on "close"-method:

> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.
>
> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

If your previous socket was successfully closed, than there should not be problems with re-instantiating that socket. This would work in Java because the JVM will free the garbage for you.

If you want multiple connections to the server (this could be useful since you're making a chat), then keep this in mind.
The accept function, on the server side, will create a new socket every time it's requested. So you can just use threads and pass the new socket (the one created using the accept) to the thread.

If this does not answer your question I would encourage you to go over the Oracle website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

and to re-formulate the question.

Comment: what about close all sockets created by accpet method from close button on server.when i make multiple client connect on the server and call socket.close from close button it close only one client not all.it seem to close on one socket instance.

Comment: "If any type of error is detected while the server is either started or running, it will immediately close all sockets, and terminate itself. If either the Client or the Server close their connections to the other, the Proxy Server will also close all sockets and terminate itseslf. It knows if either the Client or Server has disconnected because a -1 is sent. The Proxy Server listens, waiting for this to be sent, and when it is encountered, all sockets are closed."
This may help:
http://www.dwgold.com/Projects/Networking/Proxyserver/Default.aspx

Comment: when i throws socket exception from the server to close all sockets, there is no -1 sent to clients.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'reinstantiating that socket'.